# How to read inputs from console

Tags: java

i have to read from the following format.

```
1

12

23

34
```

So, All inputs are separated by a line.

I have tried the following

```
   br = new Scanner(System.in);
   num = Integer.parseInt(br.next());
   while(br.hasNextInt()) {
        num = br.nextInt() ; 
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

But it is not working as i expected. If i enter first input, it started processing it and prints. it is not waiting for me to enter next line. In C, i can make use of sscanf. but in java i have no idea how to allow user to enter multiline input? plese suggest some ideas

Answer (score 1):

You must check for next available input and then get the input

```
br = new Scanner(System.in);
//num = Integer.parseInt(br.next());//remove this line
while(br.hasNextInt()) {//if number is avaialable
     num = br.nextInt(); //get that number
     System.out.println(num);
}
```

Below is [sample code](http://ideone.com/mAbqoB):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNextInt())
            System.out.printf("input was: %d\n",sc.nextInt());
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`br = new Scanner(System.in);
     while (true) {
              int num = Integer.parseInt(br.nextLine());
              System.out.println(num);
     }`

Comment: On second thought, the true should be replaced, but I need more context to improve it further

Comment: this doesn't terminate in the end. it will throw exception

Answer (score 0):

```
   br = new Scanner(System.in);
   num = Integer.parseInt(br.next());
   br.nextLine();
     while(br.hasNextInt()) {
            num = br.nextInt() ; 
            br.nextLine();
            System.out.println(num);
        }
```

you need to add `br.nextLine();` to start to read next line.

Comment: No, It doesn't work. It works like  "input [prints] next_input [print]".  I expect input next_input [print inpur next_input]

Comment: First i have to get all the numbers and the n i want to process

Comment: @user3801433 I have resolved your code only. It will print as like your code. I didnt change anything. I  just added nextLine(). It moved pointer to next line in scanner

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely obvious what you require , but this code ( below ) will allow you to read and store multiple lines of input , and then print them all when you're finished .

```
systemInScanner = new Scanner ( System.in ) ;

ArrayList < String > arrayListOfStrings = new ArrayList < > ( ) ; 

while ( systemInScanner . hasNextLine ( ) ) 
{
    arrayListOfStrings . add ( systemInScanner . NextLine ( ) ) ; 
}

for ( String line : input ) 
{
    System . out . println ( line ) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you willing to read line by line . This code read line by line and exits when you input a empty line

```
br = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num=0;
        String input;
        input = br.nextLine();
        while(input.length()!=0) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println(num);
            input = br.nextLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear; however if you're trying to get the user input- then print it later, you can save the inputs to an ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers, when you're done, enter a letter.");
        char firstLetter = '*';
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        while(!Character.isLetter(firstLetter)) {
            String input = "";
            boolean nullInput = false;
            do{
                if(nullInput)
                    System.out.println("Error; you can't enter an empty string.");
                nullInput = false;
                input = in.nextLine();
                if(input.length() == 0)
                    nullInput = true;
            }while(nullInput);
            firstLetter = input.charAt(0);
            al.add(input);
        }
        al.remove(al.size()-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(); //creates newline in console
            System.out.println(al.get(i));

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new.scanner(System.in);
String abc = scanner.next();
int a = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int ch;
        while ((ch = br.read()) != -1) {
            if (ch == 10) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```